# Dividing work among threads

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, boost-thread

I know there are similar questions, but none of them answered my question.

I'm trying to divide a big loop(2^60) into several smaller loops distributed among threads. The range of loop can vary from (2^4) to (2^60). My question is how do I decide the optimal number(max=8, min=1) of threads and how to divide the work among them. If someone can show with an example that would be great.

For example.. I was trying to divide 2^32 among 8 threads. So every thread will do 2^29 amount of work, right? but how do I divide the range? (0... 2^29),(2^29....2^30)... ? Sorry if that's poor mathematics but my minds not working properly anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy thing to do is just divide the number with number of threads and use it. Let m=floor(n/k). 0..(m-1), m..(2m-1).... are the starts and ends of loops.

Not sure why you are obsessing `2^a`s. Is there any specific reason? Otherwise do as you would do for any other range. Divide equally.

Comment: @Elkamina- The question is how to decide the number of threads, based on the range, which is nether too high nor too low.

Comment: @questions That depends on lots of other stuff! How many cores you have, how long can you afford to wait, how much memory you have, how much memory each thread consumes, what is the IO time for each thread... In a simple computationally intensive scenario that doesn't need much RAM I would say run as many threads as the number of cores in your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Intervals of 2E29 go like this:

```
0 * 2E29 ~ 1 * 2E29    =     0           ~ 2E29
1 * 2E29 ~ 2 * 2E29    =     2E29        ~ 2E30
2 * 2E29 ~ 3 * 2E29    =     2E30        ~ 2E30 + 2E29
3 * 2E29 ~ 4 * 2E29    =     2E30 + 2E29 ~ 2E31
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the intervals that I I got

```
(0, 2^29 - 1)

(2^29, 2^30 - 1)

(2^30, 2^30 + 2^29 -1)

(2^30 + 2^29, 2^31 - 1)

(2^31, 2^31 + 2^29 - 1)

(2^31 + 2^29, 2^31 + 2^30 - 1)

(2^31 + 2^30, 2^31 + 2^30 + 2^29 - 1)

(2^31 + 2^30 + 2^29, 2^32 - 1)
```

you probably are confused because `2^29 + 2^29 = 2^30` (a monomial).  However `2^30 + 2^29` can't be added into a monomial